# Expansion of Brackets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Case 1: $(a.b)(c.d)$

Case 2: $(e+f)(g+h)$

In both cases if you a value for the for each letter just calculate each bracket and multiply by the value of the second bracket.

If no values are given Case 1 is still relatively simple as multiplication is commutative and the only operation is multiplication is the only operation so $(a.b)(c.d)= abcd.$

If no values are given in Case 2 it is more complicated. Whilst addition is also commutative it is not the only operation. Obviously I have been taught 
$(e+f)(g+h)= eg+eh+fg+fh.$ How was this result arrived at?

Answer (score 0):

It is the distributive law applied thrice.  $$\begin{align}(e+f)(g+h)&=e(g+h)+f(g+h)\\&=eg+eh+fg+fh\end {align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Many American schools also teach a method called FOIL where F stands for first terms, O stands for outer terms, I stands for inner terms, and L stands for last terms. The first terms in the binomials are $e$ and $g$ so the first terms in the answer is $eg$. The outer terms in the binomials are $e$ and $h$ so the second term in the answer is $eh$. The inner terms in the binomials are $f$ and $g$ so the third term in the answer is $fg$. The last terms in the binomials are $f$ and $h$ so the last term in the answer is $fh$. As you see you arrive at the same answer when you add together these terms. The downfall of FOIL is that is only works when multiplying two binomials while repeated application of the distributive property works when multiplying any two polynomials.